# What is the best choice(WinForm or WPF) to design a software in accounting field?

Tags: wpf, winforms

I want to design an important software in accounting field. This software will be used in a local network. The bank is SQL server 2008 R2. What is the best choice(WinForm or WPF technology) to design this software?

Answer (score 3):

First consider if it has to be a local client type app. There are already ERP systems running as WebApps, and more are comming.

If not: Winforms are so 90's - No matter what the preconditions are, you are better of using a technology from this century: WPF, using VMMV or similar.
- if you don't need the full framework, consider SilverLight. This allows the app to also work on Macs, and does scale a lot better in terms of both deployment and development.

Comment: I think you meant "MVVM" there. ;)

Comment: ha ha -yeah, I use the patterns more than the acronyms ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Now that I know WPF, I'm completely done with WinForms.  WPF is a superior technology in every respect.  It makes better UIs, and using data binding intelligently (MVVM is 80-90% of that) makes it much easier to develop reliable UIs faster.

That "now that I know WPF" part is critical.  That knowledge did not come easily.  (Though there's a ton more information available today than there was when I started out with it.)  It took me months to get good at it.

Comment: +1 I agree completely. Obviously delivery requirements make a difference: if you're proficient with WinForms and have to deliver in six weeks, the ramp-up on WPF is probably unacceptable. But, all else being equal, WPF is definitely worth the effort.

Answer (score 1):

How complex is the UI going to be? If you want to make a real interactive UI, then you would want to use the powers of WPF. But if its just going to be basic data input/output type of stuff, then WinForms might be fine for you. Also keep in mind the version of .NET that will be required for the users, so see what where they are at in those terms as well.